# How to mass insert data into a MySQL database table with same data field name?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have a structure which capture MULTIPLE email address(es) , on the same page but with same  fields (e.g. email)

```
<form action=process.php method=POST>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input type=button>
</form>
```

How can I use a PHP file (process.php) to insert the data into separate records ? such as

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'xxxxxx';
$dbusername = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbpassword = 'xxxxxxxx';

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);

$statement = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO tablex (email) VALUES (:email)');

$statement->execute([
'email' => $_POST["email"]
]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you will need to change the

```
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
<input name=email><br>
```

to

```
<input name=email[]><br>
<input name=email[]><br>
<input name=email[]><br>
```

and then in your php file, please use a loop to process the data , such as

```
$xcount= count($_POST["email"]); 
$index=0;

while ($index < $xcount) {

   if (isset($_POST["email"][$index]) && $_POST["email"][$index] !="") {

      $statement = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO tablex (email) VALUES (:email)');

      $statement->execute([
         'email' => $_POST["email"][$index]
     ]);
   }

}
```

Comment: You can insert multiple rows as at the same time with `VALUES (:email0),(:email1),(:email2)`